# LaTex CV - Deedy Resume: How to change the font family of bullet points/how to make it bold?

Tags: xetex, cv, deedy-resume

I'm working on modifying the Deedy CV template ([link here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz#.U2H9Kq1dV18)). I would like to change the font weight of the bullet points as it is very light. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to the preamble

```
\setmainfont[Color=primary,
 Path = fonts/lato/,
 Extension=.ttf,
 UprightFont=*-Reg,
 BoldItalicFont=*-BolIta,
 BoldFont=*-Bol,
 ItalicFont=*-RegIta]
 {Lato}
```

Before
[image: a]

After

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex


\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

    
\setmainfont[Color=primary, % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 Path = fonts/lato/,
 Extension=.ttf,
 UprightFont=*-Reg,
 BoldItalicFont=*-BolIta,
 BoldFont=*-Bol,
 ItalicFont=*-RegIta]
 {Lato}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
 
\begin{document}

... your document here <<<<<<

\end{document}
```